# Binding custom object to Property grid

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to bind a custom object list to a dropdown in a property grid

```
public class Myclass{
[category("property settings")]
public ObjType DropValue{get;set;}
}

public class ObjType {
public int id;
public string name;
}
```

Comment: Or [better this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24503462/1997232).

Comment: I would like to bind a complex object like the one shown in the example to a drop down in a property grid. I need to bind both id and name to the drop down and only display the name.